# Why do I have multiple command line input arrows using zsh?

Tags: terminal, zsh, iterm2

here is my zshrc

```
if [[ -r "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh" ]]; then
  source "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh"
fi
export ZSH="/Users/gansaikhanshur/.oh-my-zsh"
ZSH_THEME="powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k"
plugins=(
    git
    zsh-syntax-highlighting
)
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
[[ ! -f ~/.p10k.zsh ]] || source ~/.p10k.zsh
test -e "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.zsh" && source "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.zsh"
```

I am using Iterm2 with Oh-my-Zsh. yet I have 3 command line input line arrows as such.

[image]

I want only the green one (which is supposed to be the default with powerlevel10k). Why is that? How can I fix this?

Comment: What three arrows are you referring to?

Comment: @chepner the three ones left to my cursor ">~ >" that thing. it's supposed to be just ">".

Comment: `~` isn't an arrow; it's a tilde, commonly used in shells to represent your home directory. This isn't a programming question, but a shell configuration question.

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with how the prompt is configured (see `man zshmisc`), especially if you want to modify a pre-built configuration.

Comment: @chepner thanks for your comment! I understand! thank you! do you have any clue what the first arrow is? or how I could get rid of that thing

Comment: It's decorative. My advice is to not use pre-made configurations without understanding what they do or how to override them. Go back and read the `zshmisc` man page to first understand *how* the prompt is configured, then look at the relavant files from oh-my-zsh to see how they *use* the features provided by `zsh`, and make whatever changes you like to create the prompt you want.

Comment: @GansaikhanShur : Something like `PS1='> '`?

Comment: @user1934428 It's may not that simple, if the theme redefines `PS1` each time a prompt is displayed. Whatever manual change you make will just be overridden immediately.

Comment: @chepner : I thought that Oh-My-Zsh package just configures a PS1, and if I set my PS1 manually afterwards, it won't change back. But if there are callbacks in effect which modify the settings before each prompt (a creepy idea!), this would not work, but the OP simply could then remove the theme definition completely. What's the point in installing a theme, if I only want to have a single `>` sign as a prompt?

Comment: oh-my-zsh does't really "do" anything; it's just a collection of pre-made configuration files that you can install as a group, along with perhaps a bunch of helper functions to help write those files. Many prompts are much easier to write by building them up in a `precmd` hook, rather than trying to cram a bunch of logic into a single string to be evaluated when `PS1` is displayed. Nothing about a theme is "necessary"; it's just a convenient way to package and share a particular prompt definition.

Comment: I installed oh-my-zsh once, years ago. I discovered I didn't really like everything it set up, so I uninstalled it, dug through the files for the stuff I *did* like, and added them to my own custom `zsh` configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The light blue triangle on the left is not from zsh but from iTerm2.

See the discussion here:

- https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/5088

To get rid of that triangle, use the iTerm2 menu to access

> Preferences > Profiles > (the relevant profile) > Terminal > Shell Integration

and uncheck "Show mark indicators".